# How to read a href parameter in servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

on address bar : http://localhost:8080/tryupload/downloadservlet?bookid=15bk
bookid=15bk (15bk was i got from my bookId on database, by getString on servlet)

then , below is my display on servlet (not jsp)

```
out.println("<TD><a href=downloadservlet?bookId=" + rs.getString(1)+ ">Download</A></TD>");
```

then it goes to
downloadservlet.java // but it didnt worked. Blank page.

How read the "boookid " from  this link  http://localhost:8080/tryupload/downloadservlet?bookid=15bk to my servlet?  and be execute on my downloadservlet.java?

**downloadservlet.java**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                String bookId = request.getParameter("bookId");

        Connection conn = null; // connection to the database

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

            // queries the database
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookId = ?";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, bookId);

            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                // gets file name and file blob data
                String fileName = result.getString("BookContent");
                Blob blob = result.getBlob("BookContent");
                InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
                int fileLength = inputStream.available();

                System.out.println("fileLength = " + fileLength);

                ServletContext context = getServletContext();

                // sets MIME type for the file download
                String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
                if (mimeType == null) {        
                    mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
                }              

                // set content properties and header attributes for the response
                response.setContentType(mimeType);
                response.setContentLength(fileLength);
                String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
                response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

                // writes the file to the client
                OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                outStream.close();             
            } else {
                // no file found
                response.getWriter().print("File not found for the id: " + bookId);  
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            response.getWriter().print("SQL Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            response.getWriter().print("IO Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }          
        }


    }
```

Comment: This is futile since you have not posted any stack trace and possible code that breaks. We cannot divinely guess what your code issue is by just reading your sample code.

Comment: @Nic, you keep changing your code which makes kinda difficult to help - you'll need to provide the error (for sure Integer.parseInt on non integer did throw exception) so it can be easily point to the root cause of the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
String bookId = request.getParameter("bookid");
```

If your parameter value is `15bk` then your line of code:

```
int bookid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("bookid"));
```

Will throw `NumberFormatException` as `bk` cannot be converted into an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

you read the parameter correctly with

```
request.getParameter("bookid")
```

However you cannot apply directly `Integer.parseInt` as you read 15bk and which is not an integer, if you need 15 out of 15 bk you need an additional step of parsing.

Following your last edit, its the same issue - you cannot do

```
statement.setInt(1, bookid);
```

bookid will not be an int. you need to parse, not sure but for example if you want to eliminate the last 2 characters you could do

```
bookIntId = bookId.substrings(0, bookId.length - 2)
```

Comment: whats the type of `bookId` column in your table ?

Comment: it was string/varchar on database. I  was wrong to paste the code on my question for the first.